# Is there a way to ensure the contents of a field are either NULL or UNIQUE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server 2012 database. My table called `REFERENCE` has a column called `LOCATOR`.

My users are entering data but sometimes they enter two different rows with the same `LOCATOR`. Is there a way I can make this create an error that appears **only** if the `LOCATOR` is not null ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what a `UNIQUE` constraint does (in most DBMS), not allow 2 rows with same value in a column - while ignoring `NULL` values.

The problem is that SQL-Server has implemented unique constraints differently than other DBMS and does not allow more than one rows with `NULL` when a unique constraint or index is defined on a column.

The solution is to use a partial index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Locator_UQ                -- name of the index
ON Reference (Locator)
WHERE Locator IS NOT NULL ;
```

Minimal test at: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a5d89/3)

Comment: Thanks very much. I did not know such a thing existed.